# Photographed monitor screen effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: img]

I am trying to achieve the exact effect as on the image above, starting from a screenshot. Any links to similar PS tutorials would be of great help.

Comment: .. I believe that's an actual photo of a monitor, not a Photoshopped screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Free Transform or the 3D-Tools to give the screenshot perspective.

[image: Transform]

2. Apply a Depth of Field effect by using either Tilt-Shift (Filter > Blur Gallery > Tilt Shift) or Lens Blur (Filter > Blur > Lens Blur)

[image: Add Blur]

Optionally you can add scanlines, grain and color adjustments.

[Tutorial on 3D-Tools](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-basic-guide-to-photoshops-3d-tools--psd-6042)
[Tutorial on Lens Blur](http://www.practicalphotoshopmag.com/2012/11/08/photoshop-lens-blur-take-precise-control-over-depth-of-field-post-shoot/)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple… first you can add some scanlines (or not) and then you do a special blur based on perspective. Maybe you can saturate a little bit more the colors, add add some grain.